# "Chaining" Meteor subscriptions

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I'm using React and `createContainer`. I'm looking for a way which I can chain together two calls.

For example, if I had this data:

```
// Category
{
   _id: 'ABC',
   name: 'Cat 1'
}

// Item
{
   catId: 'ABC',
   slug: 'slug'
}
```

In my `createContainer`, I want to get the `Item` by it's slug (`Items.find({ slug })`). I then want to turn around and get the category by the `item.catId`.

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
 createContainer(({ slug }) => {
     const itemHandler = Meteor.subscribe('Item.bySlug', slug);
     const item = Items.findOne();

     const categoryHandler = Meteor.subscribe('Category.byId', (item.id || {}).id); // also tried just item.id and got undefined for item
     const category = Categories.findOne();

     return { item, category };
 }, Component);
```

I can get `item` just fine, but no dice on `category`, it remains undefined. I'm sure I'm not triggering something reactively, but I'm not quite sure what the correct pattern would be in this case, or if there is a more streamline way.

Comment: Would this package not work for you? https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the code I posted does work, I just had a data issue where `Items.categoryId` wasn't being populated properly.

In this particular instance, I did want to do a client-side join, and what I did does work. The item bit is react, and once it loads, it'll actually rerun and then properly populate that field.

```
createContainer(({ slug }) => {
     const itemHandler = Meteor.subscribe('Item.bySlug', slug);
     const item = Items.findOne();

     const categoryHandler = Meteor.subscribe('Category.byId', (item.id || {}).id); // also tried just item.id and got undefined for item
     const category = Categories.findOne();

     return { item, category };
 }, Component);
```

The first run through, `item` will be defined and `category` will be null. The next go through (as soon as `item` is ready) will then populate `category`. Takes two hops, but works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to your problem is to return an `array` of `cursors` from the server side `publication` and call `collection.findOne()` in the client side after `subscription`.

Publication code would be something like this:

```
Meteor.publish("your.publication.name", function(slug, id){
    let itemCursor = Items.find(your_selector);
    let categoryCursor = Categories.find(your_selector);
  return [itemCursor, categoryCursor];
});
```

Now you will get necessary documents from Item and Category collection in the client side.

Comment: This is the simplest solution to this particular problem when you're publishing a single document from a collection and a related document from another.

Answer (score 0):

you're essentially doing a client-side join. in these situations, i typically do a server-side join. here, in the Item.bySlug publisher, i would do something like this:

```
let itemCursor = Items.find({slug: slug});

let transformItem = (fields) => {
    // making an assumption here that Item has a categoryId that indicates its category
    let category = Categories.findOne(fields.categoryId);

    // attach the category to the Item
    fields.category = category;

    return fields;
};

let handle = itemCursor.observeChanges({
    added: (id, fields) => {
        fields = transformItem(fields);
        this.added('items', id, fields);
    },
    changed: (id, fields) => {
        fields = transformItem(fields);
        this.changed('items', id, fields);
    },
    removed: (id) => {
        this.removed('items', id);
    }
});

this.ready();

this.onStop(() => {
    handle.stop();
});
```

now, on the client, you need only subscribe to the Item you want, and its category will be attached.